# Cannot Remove Field from Sharepoint AddIn

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, custom-list, column

I have a provider-hosted SharePoint Online add-in project. In this project I have added a lookup field with name **CaseLawyer** and deployed the app in the site.
After that, I have deleted this field form the list and added a new lookup field with name **AuthorizedTo** and upgraded my app. Now when I open the list view 
I still see the old field (CaseLawyer) and don't see the new field (AuthorizedTo).

This is how I created the list: 
[image]

and this is the view of the list:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expand your "Case" list item in the solution explorer and edit the "Schema.xml" file in order to remove all reference to the field you want to delete.

I once have similar problem with a field i have renamed and it didn't work with the list designer but succeed on editing directly the schema.